# What are these errors? how can I fix them?

Tags: c++

I am learning c++ and I am writing a card dealer program. When I compile my code and I get these errors:

```
dealer3.cpp:12: error: expected initializer before ‘int’
dealer3.cpp:33: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘=’ token
dealer3.cpp:34: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘=’ token
dealer3.cpp:35: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘=’ token
dealer3.cpp:36: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘=’ token
dealer3.cpp:37: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘<<’ token
dealer3.cpp:38: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
```

and here is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int randn(int n);
void draw();
int uni(int n);
char *suits[4]={"Hearts","Diamonds","spades","clubs"};
char *ranks[13]={"ace","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","jack","queen","king"};
int drawn[52];
int remaining=52;
int main() {
    int n;
    int i;
    srand(time(NULL));
    while(1) {
       cout<<"enter number of cards to draw"<<endl;
       cin>>n;
       if (n==0) break;

for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
    draw();
}

    return 0;
}
int r;
int s;
int n;
int card;
n=randn(remaining--);
card=uni(n);
    r=card%13;
    s=card/13;
    cout<<ranks[r]<<" of "<<suit[s]<<endl;
}
int uni(int n)
{
int i=0;
while (drawn[i])
    i++;
while (n-->0){
    i++;
while (drawn[i])
    i++;
}
card_drawn([i])=true;
return i;
}
int randn (int n){
return rand()%n;
}
```

Why is this?

Comment: So, what's your question? Did you read the error messages?

Comment: yes I did read the errors but I dont undersand what to do

Comment: Start by properly indenting your code, please?

Comment: You've got an unmatched right brace at line 38, and code outside any function (like calling randn() at line 33).  The draw() function is totally missing, which might explain all that code in block zero.  Did you mean for all that code beginning at line 29 to be the draw() function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, this is a nice case where indenting the code would solve your problem (or make the solution very obvious), as it would show up several errors in with your braces. You have several lines of code that are outside of any function that don't belong there.

Some formatting hints for you:

- Indent each nested block of code by a fixed amount of spaces (usually 4).
- Leave a blank line after every function.
- When opening a new block for a function or a `for`-, `while`- or `if`-statement (the list goes on), take care that you place your opening brackets consistently (the same style all over your code).
- make sure that a bracket that closes a block is at the same indentation level as the statement/bracket that opened it.

Note that most IDEs have some option to automatically fix formatting for you (especially the indentation).

Comment: And in one fell swoop he declares the goodness of one bracketing style and the not-goodness of another.  Do you have any idea how long that argument has been going on and how completely unresolved it is and will forever remain?  ;-)

Comment: carey he got here first plus I cant mark a comment as a correct answer

Comment: @Nick: I'm not disputing his answer; his answer is correct.  I'm simply making fun of him declaring one style of indentation "good" and another style "not good."  Arguments have been waged for decades over that question and I assure you there is no agreed upon answer.

Comment: @Carey: Agreed. I much prefer the curlies under the `if`, `while`, etc., and I have no clue how this relates to the error. To each his own, so there is no "good" or "not good".

Comment: Ok, I changed that part to a recommendation about consistency.

Answer (score 1):

You have a missing brace. And the following statement(s) goes in global space -

```
n=randn(remaining--);
// ...
```